Как подружить между собой vite (react-ts) eslint-plugin airbnb-typescript?
Проблема в следующем: есть проект, развернутый с помощью vite (react-ts). Есть непреодолимое желание добавить airbnb-typescript в eslintrc.cjs. После всех манипуляций согласно документации пакета и запуске npm run lint
в консоли видим ошибкуParsing error: ESLint was configured to run on <tsconfigRootDir>/vite.config.ts using parserOptions.project: <tsconfigRootDir>/tsconfig.eslint.json. Подскажите, как их подружить???
eslintrc.cjs:
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "airbnb-typescript",
    "prettier",
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ["dist", ".eslintrc.cjs"],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "./tsconfig.eslint.json",
  },
  plugins: ["react-refresh", "react-compiler", "prettier"],
rules: {...}

tsconfig.eslint.json:
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
 "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.js", "test/**/*.ts"]
}

package.json:
 "lint": "eslint ./src/ --ext ts,tsx --max-warnings 0"

